# PHP with Javascript to access database

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, database

Suppose I define a an application in php 
which has as into the  Tag as an internal javascript 
and a variable 'abc' defined into the js as follows :

```
var abc;
```

now i want to assign a new value to the variable which will be fetched from a MySQL db

example :

```
var abc = $mysql(select id from dB_table where .....xyz )
```

will it be under the scope of abc to retrieve date from MySQL db?
how is it achievable?

PS : i will be using php to connect to the db

```
mysql_connect(servername,username,password)
```

Comment: If you want to perform this update any time after page-load time, you'll want to fetch a new value from the server with Ajax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: So wait.. You want to use JavaScript to connect to your database? Not only is that very difficult, it's a terrible idea.

Comment: It is not possible at client side.

Comment: @Senen I have posted a way in which you can access the PHP/SQL values in Javascript below.

Answer (score 5):

STOP STOP STOP **STOP**. Horribly stupid idea... if you're specifying SQL in client-side code, what's to stop someone from doing

```
var haha_im_in_ur_server = $mysql("delete from db_Table");
```

**THINK** about how extraordinarily dangerous such a system will be. If you enjoy getting your server destroyed in a every-other-second basis, then feel free to implement it yourself.